# Dropwizard, swagger and in-memory hiverunner/hiveqlunit integration

Tags: maven, reflection, hive, swagger, dropwizard

I am having some trouble trying to run an in-memory `hive` while writing tests for a `dropwizard` `swagger` app. I have tried both `hiverunner` and `hiveqlunit`.

There are 2 types of tests. One is for testing `dropwizard`/`swagger` API endpoints using `dropwizard` integration testing (no need for `hive` here) and the other is for testing the `hive` integration where I need to hit the api and setup an in-memory `hive` to query and verify data is stored in `hiveDB` (psql).

The two in-memory `hive` dependencies (Note that I am using one at a time) always have some kind of conflict with the existing `dropwizard` and `swagger` dependencies. I am guessing it has something to do with `jersey` but I've tried a lot of things and still no luck.

I can run in-memory `hive` just fine and do all `CRUD` if I am not hitting the `dropwizard/swagger` api. But I just can't get the two services to play along at the moment.

Versions in `Maven`:

```
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core version: 0.9.2
com.smoketurner:dropwizard-swagger version: 0.9.2-3
com.facebook.presto.hive:hive-apache-jdbc version: 0.13.1-3

com.klarna:hiverunner version: 3.0.0
OR
org.finra.hiveqlunit:hiveQLUnit version: 1.0
```

`dropwizard-swagger` uses `org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10` and `com.klarna:hiverunner` uses `org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.8`.

When I didn't exclude anything, I got the following:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper.forPackage(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Collection;
```

So I tried excluding `org.reflections:reflections` from `hiverunner` and I got the 3 `Exceptions`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-73437222@8a344094==io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer,1,false
Caused by: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: method inject on com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory
```

Then I tried excluding `org.reflections:reflections` from `dropwizard-swagger` and added a separate dependency for `org.reflections:reflections` by adding the following dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And got the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/MoreObjects
```

So I added the latest `guava` (version 20.0) and then it gives me another error. This seems like dependency hell.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before? It seems like `dropwizard` and `hiverunner` do not play along well. Maybe it has to do with the versioning of `jersey` 1 & 2.

I got some other error regarding `jackson-databind`, so I did some research and found out I had to have the same version for the following dependencies:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind (from `dropwizard`)
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala (from `hiverunner/hiveqlunit`)
```

And now I am back to the previous 3 `Exceptions`...

Any help will be appreciated.

---

***Edit:*** Found out that `hiveqlunit` is using the following:

```
com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9
```

Which is one of the last versions before moving to the following `maven` dependency:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server
```

It is having conflicts with `dropwizard`'s `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.`

How can i resolve this conflict?

Comment: Whats your current pom.xml dependencies list?